# How to fix the error in connecting sql in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use the code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module Module1
    Public con As New MySqlConnection

    Sub openCon()
        con.ConnectionString = "host=127.0.0.1;username=root;password=;database=db_tutorial"
        con.Open()
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Module Make New Sub :

```
Public Sub Open_Conn_MySql()
    Try
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("data source="127.0.0.1"; port="3306"; database="db_tutorial"; user id="root"; password=""; charset=utf8;")
        
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace.ToString, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You Can Use From Any Form In Your Project AS :

```
Open_Conn_MySql()
```